# Difference between method and function in Scala

Tags: function, scala, methods

I read *[Scala Functions](http://www.naildrivin5.com/scalatour/wiki_pages/ScalaFunctions)* (part of *Another tour of Scala*). In that post he stated:

> Methods and functions are not the same thing

But he didn't explain anything about it. What was he trying to say?

Comment: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html

Comment: I think you can get something from [What is the difference between a method and a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: A follow-up question with good answers: [Functions vs methods in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala)

Answer (score 255):

Jim has got this pretty much covered in [his blog post](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html), but I'm posting a briefing here for reference.

First, let's see what the Scala Specification tell us. Chapter 3 (types) tell us about *Function Types* (3.2.9) and *Method Types* (3.3.1). Chapter 4 (basic declarations) speaks of *Value Declaration and Definitions* (4.1), *Variable Declaration and Definitions* (4.2) and *Functions Declarations and Definitions* (4.6). Chapter 6 (expressions) speaks of *Anonymous Functions* (6.23) and *Method Values* (6.7). Curiously, function values is spoken of one time on 3.2.9, and no where else.

A **Function Type** is (roughly) a type of the form *(T1, ..., Tn) => U*, which is a shorthand for the trait `FunctionN` in the standard library. **Anonymous Functions** and **Method Values** have function types, and function types can be used as part of value, variable and function declarations and definitions. In fact, it can be part of a method type.

A **Method Type** is a ***non-value type***. That means there is ***no*** value - no object, no instance - with a method type. As mentioned above, a **Method Value** actually has a **Function Type**. A method type is a `def` declaration - everything about a `def` except its body.

**Value Declarations and Definitions** and **Variable Declarations and Definitions** are `val` and `var` declarations, including both *type and value* - which can be, respectively, **Function Type** and **Anonymous Functions or Method Values**. Note that, on the JVM, these (method values) are implemented with what Java calls "methods".

A **Function Declaration**  is a `def` declaration, including *type* and *body*. The type part is the Method Type, and the body is an *expression or a block*. This is also implemented on the JVM with what Java calls "methods".

Finally, an **Anonymous Function** is an instance of a **Function Type** (ie, an instance of the trait `FunctionN`), and a **Method Value** is the same thing! The distinction is that a Method Value is created from methods, either by postfixing an underscore (`m _` is a method value corresponding to the "function declaration" (`def`) `m`), or by a process called *eta-expansion*, which is like an automatic cast from method to function.

That is what the specs say, so let me put this up-front: **we do not use that terminology!** It leads to too much confusion between so-called *"function declaration"*, which is a part of the program (chapter 4 -- basic declarations) and *"anonymous function"*, which is an expression, and *"function type"*, which is, well a type -- a trait.

The terminology below, and used by experienced Scala programmers, makes one change from the terminology of the specification: **instead of saying *function declaration*, we say *method***. Or even method declaration. Furthermore, we note that *value declarations* and *variable declarations* are also methods for practical purposes.

**So, given the above change in terminology, here's a practical explanation of the distinction.**

A *function* is an object that includes one of the `FunctionX` traits, such as `Function0`, `Function1`, `Function2`, etc. It might be including `PartialFunction` as well, which actually extends `Function1`.

Let's see the type signature for one of these traits:

```
trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef
```

This trait has one abstract method (it has a few concrete methods as well):

```
def apply(v1: T1, v2: T2): R
```

And that tell us all that there is to know about it. A *function* has an `apply` method which receives *N* parameters of types *T1*, *T2*, ..., *TN*, and returns something of type `R`. It is contra-variant on the parameters it receives, and co-variant on the result.

That variance means that a `Function1[Seq[T], String]` is a subtype of `Function1[List[T], AnyRef]`. Being a subtype means it can be used *in place of* it. One can easily see that if I'm going to call `f(List(1, 2, 3))` and expect an `AnyRef` back, either of the two types above would work.

Now, what is the *similarity* of a method and a function? Well, if `f` is a function and `m` is a method local to the scope, then both can be called like this:

```
val o1 = f(List(1, 2, 3))
val o2 = m(List(1, 2, 3))
```

These calls are actually different, because the first one is just a syntactic sugar. Scala expands it to:

```
val o1 = f.apply(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Which, of course, is a method call on object `f`. Functions also have other syntactic sugars to its advantage: function literals (two of them, actually) and `(T1, T2) => R` type signatures. For example:

```
val f = (l: List[Int]) => l mkString ""
val g: (AnyVal) => String = {
  case i: Int => "Int"
  case d: Double => "Double"
  case o => "Other"
}
```

Another similarity between a method and a function is that the former can be easily converted into the latter:

```
val f = m _
```

Scala will expand *that*, assuming `m` type is `(List[Int])AnyRef` into (Scala 2.7):

```
val f = new AnyRef with Function1[List[Int], AnyRef] {
  def apply(x$1: List[Int]) = this.m(x$1)
}
```

On Scala 2.8, it actually uses an `AbstractFunction1` class to reduce class sizes.

Notice that one can't convert the other way around -- from a function to a method.

Methods, however, have one big advantage (well, two -- they can be slightly faster): they can receive *type parameters*. For instance, while `f` above can necessarily specify the type of `List` it receives (`List[Int]` in the example), `m` can parameterize it:

```
def m[T](l: List[T]): String = l mkString ""
```

I think this pretty much covers everything, but I'll be happy to complement this with answers to any questions that may remain.

Comment: This explanation is very clear. Well done.

Unfortunately both the Odersky/Venners/Spoon book and the Scala spec use the words "function" and "method" somewhat interchangeably. (They are likeliest to say "function" where "method" would be clearer, but sometimes it happens the other way too, for example, section 6.7 of the spec, which covers converting methods to functions, is named "Method Values". Ugh.)

I think that loose use of these words has led to a lot of confusion when people try to learn the language.

Comment: @Seth I know, I know -- PinS was the book that taught me Scala. I learned better the hard way, ie, paulp set me straight.

Comment: Great explanation! I have one thing to add: When you quote the expansion of `val f = m` by the compiler as `val f = new AnyRef with Function1[List[Int], AnyRef] {
  def apply(x$1: List[Int]) = this.m(x$1)
}` you should point out that the `this` inside the `apply` method does not refer to the `AnyRef` object, but to the object in whose method the `val f = m _` is evaluated (the _outer_ `this`, so to say), since `this` is among the values that are captured by the closure (like e.g. `return` as pointed out below).

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, what is the PinS book you mentioned? I'm also interested in learning Scala, and haven't found a book with that name,

Comment: @tldr [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), by Odersky et all. It's the common abbreviation for it (they did tell me they didn't quite like PiS for some reason! :)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I'm not sure PinS is all that much better when pronounced quickly!

Comment: If you write an essay in a SO answer then please add TL;DR to the top of it.

Comment: One more reason to say Scala is the most complex language among the ones that are still alive. Hopefully, after Scala 3 or 4 will come a subset of it, without fancy academic experiments, simplified and ready to take in the mainstream.

Comment: @viyps That's utter non-sense. Compared to the Java spec this is trivial. And, just. as with the Java spec, most programmers don't need to bother with the distinction. Even if that was not the case, Scala _and_ Java complexity _pales_ in comparison with that of C++ or C#. Finally, Scala _is_ a mainstream language nowadays.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Sorry about the "fancy" part, completely unneeded. Scala is my language of choice for now, unfortunately it is losing space to crap languages like Python/JS*. Although, I have no problems saying it is (probably) the most complex language that I know of - in the sense of amount of features, type system, lots of ways to do the same thing, several paradigms etc. For those like me that use the basic tool set it is easy, but the "language" is much more than that. Every basic corner has a deeper implicit secret to learn. I agree C++ may deserve the first place -even with specs aside.

Answer (score 69):

One big practical difference between a method and a function is what `return` means.  `return` only ever returns from a method.  For example:

```
scala> val f = () => { return "test" }
<console>:4: error: return outside method definition
       val f = () => { return "test" }
                       ^
```

Returning from a function defined in a method does a non-local return:

```
scala> def f: String = {                 
     |    val g = () => { return "test" }
     | g()                               
     | "not this"
     | }
f: String

scala> f
res4: String = test
```

Whereas returning from a local method only returns from that method.

```
scala> def f2: String = {         
     | def g(): String = { return "test" }
     | g()
     | "is this"
     | }
f2: String

scala> f2
res5: String = is this
```

Comment: That's because return is captured by the closure.

Comment: I can't think of a single time I'd want to 'return' from a function to nonlocal scope. In fact, I can see that as being a serious security issue if a function can just decide it wants to go farther back up the stack. Feels kind of like longjmp, only way easier to accidentally get wrong. I've noticed scalac won't let me return from functions, though. Does that mean this abomination has been struck from the language?

Comment: @root - what about returning from inside a `for (a <- List(1, 2, 3)) { return ... }`?  That gets de-sugared to a closure.

Comment: Hmm... Well, that is a reasonable use case. Still has the potential to lead to horrible difficult-to-debug problems, but that does put it in a more sensible context.

Comment: Non-local return is also one of the better approaches when you need to "short-circuit" a fold, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12897950/154770

Comment: Honestly I'd use different syntax. have ``return`` return a value from the function, and some form of ``escape`` or ``break`` or ``continue`` to return from methods.

Answer (score 44):

> **function** A function can be invoked with a list of arguments to produce a
>   result. A function has a parameter list, a body, and a result type.
>   Functions that are members of a class, trait, or singleton object are
>   called **methods**. Functions defined inside other functions are called
>   local functions. Functions with the result type of Unit are called procedures.
>   Anonymous functions in source code are called function literals.
>   At run time, function literals are instantiated into objects called
>   function values.

[**Programming in Scala Second Edition.
Martin Odersky - Lex Spoon - Bill Venners**](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)

Comment: A function can belong to a class as a def or as a val/var. Only the def's are methods.

Answer (score 32):

Let Say you have a List

```
scala> val x =List.range(10,20)
x: List[Int] = List(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
```

Define a Method

```
scala> def m1(i:Int)=i+2
m1: (i: Int)Int
```

Define a Function

```
scala> (i:Int)=>i+2
res0: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> x.map((x)=>x+2)
res2: List[Int] = List(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
```

Method Accepting Argument

```
scala> m1(2)
res3: Int = 4
```

Defining Function with val

```
scala> val p =(i:Int)=>i+2
p: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Argument to function is Optional

```
 scala> p(2)
    res4: Int = 4

scala> p
res5: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Argument to Method is Mandatory

```
scala> m1
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method m1;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Check the following [Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O5-F6tOGmw&list=PLrUFyg1unBb_GJgmwlZ-4VjrazNCpkQEy) that explains passing other differences with examples like other example of diff with Method Vs Function, Using function as Variables, creating function that returned function

Answer (score 13):

Functions don't support parameter defaults. Methods do. Converting from a method to a function loses parameter defaults. (Scala 2.8.1)

Comment: Is there are reason for this?

Answer (score 12):

There is a nice article [here](http://www.marcinkossakowski.com/posts/2016-11-05-difference-between-functions-and-methods-in-scala.html) from which most of my descriptions are taken.
Just a short comparison of Functions and Methods regarding my understanding. Hope it helps:

**Functions**:
They are basically an object. More precisely, functions are objects with an apply method; Therefore, they  are a little bit slower than methods because of their overhead. It is similar to static methods in the sense that they are independent of an object to be invoked.
A simple example of a function is just like bellow:

```
val f1 = (x: Int) => x + x
f1(2)  // 4
```

The line above is nothing except assigning one object to another like object1  = object2. Actually the object2 in our example is an anonymous function and the left side gets the type of an object because of that. Therefore, now f1 is an object(Function). The anonymous function is actually an instance of Function1[Int, Int] that means a function with 1 parameter of type Int and return value of type Int.
Calling f1 without the arguments will give us the signature of the anonymous function (Int => Int = )

**Methods**:
They are not objects but assigned to an instance of a class,i.e., an object. Exactly the same as method in java or member functions in c++ (as [Raffi Khatchadourian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405326/raffi-khatchadourian) pointed out in a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)) and etc.
A simple example of a method is just like bellow:

```
def m1(x: Int) = x + x
m1(2)  // 4
```

The line above is not a simple value assignment but a definition of a method. When you invoke this method with the value 2 like the second line, the x is substituted with 2 and the result will be calculated and you get 4 as an output. Here you will get an error if just simply write m1 because it is method and need the input value. By using _ you can assign a method to a function like bellow:

```
val f2 = m1 _  // Int => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: What does it mean to "assign a method to a function"? Does it just mean that you now have an object that behaves the same way the method did?

Comment: @K.M :  val f2 = m1 _  is equivalent to 
           val f2 = new Function1[Int, Int] {
                    def m1(x: Int) = x + x
            };

Answer (score 4):

Here is a great [post](http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html) by Rob Norris which explains the difference, here is a TL;DR

> Methods in Scala are not values, but functions are. You can construct a function that delegates to a method via η-expansion (triggered by the trailing underscore thingy).

with the following definition:

> a **method** is something defined with **def** and a **value** is something you can assign to a **val**

In a nutshell (*extract from the blog*):

When we define a method we see that we cannot assign it to a `val`.

```scala
scala> def add1(n: Int): Int = n + 1
add1: (n: Int)Int

scala> val f = add1
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method add1;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       val f = add1
```

Note also the **type** of `add1`, which doesn’t look normal; you can’t declare a variable of type `(n: Int)Int`. Methods are not values.

However, by adding the η-expansion postfix operator (η is pronounced “eta”), we can turn the method into a function value. Note the type of `f`.

```scala
scala> val f = add1 _
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(3)
res0: Int = 4
```

The effect of `_` is to perform the equivalent of the following: we construct a `Function1` instance that delegates to our method.

```scala
scala> val g = new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(n: Int): Int = add1(n) }
g: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> g(3)
res18: Int = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Practically, a Scala programmer only needs to know the following three rules to use functions and methods properly:

- Methods defined by `def` and function literals defined by `=>` are functions. It is defined in page 143, Chapter 8 in the book of Programming in Scala, 4th edition.
- Function values are objects that can be passed around as any values. Function literals and partially applied functions are function values.
- You can leave off the underscore of a partially applied function if a function value is required at a point in the code. For example: `someNumber.foreach(println)`

After four editions of Programming in Scala, it is still an issue for people to differentiate the two important concepts: function and function value because all editions don't give a clear explanation. The language specification is too complicated. I found the above rules are simple and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.13, unlike functions, methods can take/return

- type parameters (polymorphic methods)
- implicit parameters
- dependent types

However, these restrictions are lifted in dotty (Scala 3) by [Polymorphic function types #4672](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672), for example, dotty version [0.23.0-RC1](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/announcing-dotty-0-23-0-rc1/4127) enables the [following syntax](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YHPY1DUdTVe02q65YIWtXw)

**Type parameters**

```
def fmet[T](x: List[T]) = x.map(e => (e, e))
val ffun = [T] => (x: List[T]) => x.map(e => (e, e))
```

**Implicit parameters ([context](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/context-functions.html) parameters)**

```
def gmet[T](implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = num.zero
val gfun: [T] => Numeric[T] ?=> T = [T] => (using num: Numeric[T]) => num.zero
```

**Dependent types**

```
class A { class B }
def hmet(a: A): a.B = new a.B
val hfun: (a: A) => a.B = hmet
```

For more examples, see [tests/run/polymorphic-functions.scala](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/8436ed547679dc89a427c2382b68d3f4409463dd/tests/run/polymorphic-functions.scala)

Answer (score 0):

A method belongs to an object (usually the `class`, `trait` or `object` in which you define it), whereas a function is by itself a value, and because in Scala *every value is an object*, therefore, *a function is an object*.

For example, given a method and a function below:

```
def timesTwoMethod(x :Int): Int = x * 2
def timesTwoFunction = (x: Int) => x * 2
```

The second `def` is an object of type `Int => Int` (the syntactic sugar for `Function1[Int, Int]`).

Scala made functions objects so they could be used as first-class entities. This way you can pass functions to other functions as arguments.

However, Scala can also treat methods as functions via a mechanism called *Eta Expansion*.

For example, the higher-order function `map` defined on `List`, receives another function `f: A => B` as its only parameter. The next two lines are equivalent:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(timesTwoMethod)
List(1, 2, 3).map(timesTwoFunction)
```

When the compiler sees a `def` given in a place where a function is needed,   it automatically converts the method into an equivalent function.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is subtle but substantial and it is related to the type system in use (besides the nomenclature coming from Object Oriented or Functional paradigm).

When we talk about a ***function***, we talk about the *type* Function: it being a type, an instance of it can be passed around as input or output to other functions (at least in the case of Scala).

When we talk about a ***method*** (of a class), we are actually talking about the *type* represented by the class it is part of: that is, the method is just a component of a larger type, and cannot be passed around by itself. It must be passed around with the instance of the type it is part of (i.e. the instance of the class).

Answer (score -2):

A method operates on an object but a function doesn't.

Scala and C++ has Fuction  but in JAVA, you have to imitate them with static methods.